# ValidationError in Django Model

Tags: python, xml, django, django-models

I defined the `Test` model as:

```
class Test(models.Model):

    name = models.BinaryField(blank=False)
    time = models.TimeField()

    # one test case has many tests
    testcase = models.ForeignKey(TestCase)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

when I try to parse a `xml` file to create the model object I have the following method:

```
def add_test(testcase, obj):
    kwargs = {
        'name': "",
        'time': None,
    }
    status = 1
    # create the test object
    for k, v in obj.iteritems():
        if k == '@name':
            kwargs['name'] = v if v is not None else ""
        elif k == '@time':
            kwargs['time'] = v
    print kwargs
    test = Test(testcase=testcase, **kwargs)
    test.save()
```

There, `testcase` is the oject of the `TestCase` model. The `kwargs` have the correct input:

```
{'name': u'runTest', 'time': u'36.332'}
```

However, when I invoke the above function I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dbsync.py", line 131, in <module>
    add_testsuite("scale")
  File "dbsync.py", line 55, in add_testsuite
    add_testcases(testsuite, testcases)
  File "dbsync.py", line 87, in add_testcases
    status = add_test(testcase_obj, testcase)
  File "dbsync.py", line 103, in add_test
    test.save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 710, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 738, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 822, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 861, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 920, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 970, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 928, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 710, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2293, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2288, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2275, in to_python
    params={'value': value},
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError
```

I don't quite get what's going on there ... any clues?

Comment: Isn't 'time' should be an instance of datetime.time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work you have to convert your string into a datetime.time.

```
kwargs['time'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(v, 'YOUR_TIME_FORMAT').time()
```

Replace YOUR_TIME_FORMAT with the input time format you have.

Answer (score 1):

It's not complaining about the way you pass in your variables, it's raising a `ValidationError` and I have a funny feeling that it's missing the last line of the traceback, which would tell us what is wrong with your values.

I didn't test the `BinaryField`, but the `TimeField` is complaining about your value. I haven't tested the BinaryField, but just looking at the `TimeField`, shows the following:

```
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/paco/Projects/sandeepbox/stackoverflow/bla/bla/field_validation.py", line 16, in <module>
    print a.is_valid()
  File "/home/paco/.virtualenvs/berou/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 184, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/home/paco/.virtualenvs/berou/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 176, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/home/paco/.virtualenvs/berou/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 392, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "/home/paco/.virtualenvs/berou/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 407, in _clean_fields
    value = field.clean(value)
  File "/home/paco/.virtualenvs/berou/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 162, in clean
    value = self.to_python(value)
  File "/home/paco/.virtualenvs/berou/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 474, in to_python
    return super(TimeField, self).to_python(value)
  File "/home/paco/.virtualenvs/berou/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 423, in to_python
    for format in self.input_formats:
  File "/home/paco/.virtualenvs/berou/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 136, in __wrapper__
    res = func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
  File "/home/paco/.virtualenvs/berou/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/formats.py", line 110, in get_format
    for module in get_format_modules(lang):
  File "/home/paco/.virtualenvs/berou/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/formats.py", line 82, in get_format_modules
    modules = _format_modules_cache.setdefault(lang, list(iter_format_modules(lang, settings.FORMAT_MODULE_PATH)))
  File "/home/paco/.virtualenvs/berou/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/formats.py", line 51, in iter_format_modules
    if not check_for_language(lang):
  File "/home/paco/.virtualenvs/berou/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 181, in check_for_language
    return _trans.check_for_language(lang_code)
  File "/home/paco/.virtualenvs/berou/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 125, in wrapper
    result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/paco/.virtualenvs/berou/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 409, in check_for_language
    if not language_code_re.search(lang_code):
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

with the following code (no need for models to show the validation):

```
from django import forms


class Test(forms.Form):
    time = forms.TimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


kwargs = {'time': u'36.332'}
a = Test(kwargs)
print a.is_valid()
```

You need to pass in your data this way:

```
import datetime

from django import forms


class Test(forms.Form):
    time = forms.TimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


kwargs = {'time': datetime.datetime.now().time()}
a = Test(kwargs)
print a.is_valid()
```

The code, this time, actually prints `True`